# Is blending 15% methanol with petrol a good idea?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I just came to know that the Government of India is going to implement a scheme under which 15 percent methanol will be blended with petrol and which will reduce the cost of the fuel by 10 percent.

I want to know that how would this practically affect all the machines where petrol is being used as fuel? Will those machines have to be reengineered to work with the new blended petrol or would those machines work the same way they worked with normal petrol? How would their efficiency be affected?

Comment: I think one reason methanol hasn't been used as an oxygenated fuel additive in other countries is that it can attack engine components like gaskets. It will also raise the vapor pressure of the fuel and could result in higher VOC emissions at the pump and venting from the tank. It could help reduce some unwanted emissions, but I don't know why it would reduce the cost of the fuel by so much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanol_fuel

Comment: There are two reasons why methanol may require caution: it is toxic to people (so you need to take care not to spill it) and it is much more corrosive to the chemicals used in gaskets (so you may have to redesign many engine parts). combustion-wise it isn't a problem, but many countries have avoided it because of those other problems and have chosen ethanol instead. But this often fails to be "greener" as the production of ethanol isn't usually green and diverts source material from food production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's important to first understand why methanol is added to petrol to begin with, outside of what I will discuss later on as some of the benefits to atmospheric emissions.

For internal combustion engines, petrol should be of a high "octane rating". This is a measure of the compression ratio of the fuel, and it needs to be high in order for the engine to work efficiently. If the petrol has too low of an octane rating, then something called knocking can occur, which over time can cause very bad engine damage.

In order to improve the octane rating of petrol then, a variety of compounds can be added that boost the overall octane rating (appropriately named octane boosters). In the past this has included tetraethyl lead, which when burned during combustion lead to the accumulation of lead in the atmosphere, which was enormously damaging to the environment and to human health. Methanol, and other alcohols like ethanol, are one such example of an octane booster.

Before I discuss the effects on engine performance, I will say that the use of using methanol blended fuel does have positive environmental impacts over the use of diesel or just straight petrol. **Combustion efficiency is improved**, thus leading to lower emissions of $\ce{NO}$ and $\ce{NO2}$ (collectively called $\ce{NOx}$ gases), which has positive implications for the atmosphere overall (lower $\ce{NOx}$ generally leads to lower ground level ozone, but this is dependent on VOC emissions of course!), as well as to lower particulate emissions. They also do not contain sulfur, and thus blended mixes have a lower sulfur load - that means less sulfur dioxide emissions.

In terms of redesigning engines on the basic, fundamental level - no change is required. Any internal combustion engine can use blended fuels, it just has implications of the lifetime of the engine. However, methanol can act as a corrosive on certain components of the engine. As blended fuels are increasingly seen as a good way for governments to reduce their $\ce{NOx}$ emissions - particularly after the problem with diesel emissions over the last decade - it seems likely that manufacturers will respond to this by redesigning engines to resist the corrosive effect of methanol within the blend. For now, though, having a small ratio of methanol to petrol - and it seems in this case, India has designed for 15% methanol blend, which should have little impact on engine damage through corrosion - is sufficient.

One last thing to note, however, that may not have come up. Some people might wonder why we don't just a 100% methanol fuel once we design engines that don't corrode due to it. The simple answer is - it's not as fuel efficient as petrol!